# How to get source of lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

I have 2 quick Action buttons, which call same lightning components.

How should I know on component initialization that which Quick Action triggered lighting component?

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that's not possible today. One way I can think of doing this would be having a parent wrapper Lightning component to pass an attribute to the child lightning component to let the child component know about current context. Something like below. This will even work when you have same component in multiple actions on a same page. Only issue is you will end up having that many parent wrapper components means if you use the component at two different places you will end up creating two different parents!

Look at @KeithC answer in [How to call a WebService method from a Lightning Component that replaces a Classic JavaScript button?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222994/how-to-call-a-webservice-method-from-a-lightning-component-that-replaces-a-class/223022#223022)

Pseudo code: In the below example you have 2 different parent components and same child component.

**Action1:**

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute
<aura:attribute name="context" type="String" default="context1"/>
    <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->
    <!-- Optional HTML markup -->
<c:child context={!v.context}/>
</aura:component>
```

**Action2:**

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute
<aura:attribute name="context" type="String" default="context2"/>
    <!-- Optional coponent attributes here -->
    <!-- Optional HTML markup -->
<c:child context={!v.context}/>
</aura:component>
```

In the meanwhile you could upvote for the idea [Ability to pass parameters to lighting component from quick actions in lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRQMQA2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85350/discussion-between-codeyinthecloud-and-jayant-das).

Comment: I had the same requirement and did not find any other solution - have a look at my [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155267/lightning-component-quick-action-send-parameters-to-the-lightning-component)

Comment: @ItaiShmida  you can try voting for the idea I created. I updated it in my answer!

Comment: excellent!!! voted

Answer (score 0):

On a totally different train of thought, if you wanted to navigate to a full-screen Lightning Component you could implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable` in your component and have your buttons be link buttons instead. Then each button could pass different parameters to the component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

Be aware that URL addressable components get cached for when you come back to them again. You will want to implement an init method that checks the state parameters, but also an `onPageReferenceChanged` method which re-checks the state and re-inits the component to whatever you want it to be when you return to it again.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround to pass one parameter (besides record Id) is to name the quick action API name like so:
**ParamVal_XXX_QuickActionName**

Example: a quick action with API Name **Foo_XXX_Quickie** created on Account object

Then in your LWC, you can parse the Param Value off the quick action API name like so:

```
import { api, wire } from "lwc";
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
............

@wire(CurrentPageReference)
parseParam(CurrentPageReference){
    let quickActionPath = currentPageReference.attributes.apiName; // Account.Foo_XXX_Quickie
    let paramValue = quickActionPath.split(".")[1].split("_XXX_")[0]; // Foo
}
```